# Off rightmost set bit of an integer

Tags: c++, c, bit

All I need to off the rightmost set bit. 
My approach is to find the position of right most bit, then off that bit. I write this code to do so..

```
int POS(int n)
{
    int p=0;

    while(n)
    {
        if(n%2==0)
        {
            p++;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }  
        n=n/2;
     }
     return p;
  }

 int main(void)
 {

 int n=12;
 int p = POS(n);
 printf("%d \n", n&~(1<<p));

 return 0;

 }
```

Is there any simplest way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/turn-off-the-rightmost-set-bit/

```
/* unsets the rightmost set bit of n and returns the result */
int fun(unsigned int n)
{
  return n&(n-1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about clearing the least significant bit *that is currently set,* use:

```
num = num & (num - 1);
```

The reasoning behind this is that a number like `xxxx1000` (where `x` means "original value") will become `xxxx0111` when you subtract one, and anding those two values gives:

```
  xxxx1000
& xxxx0111
  --------
  xxxx0000
```

clearing the rightmost one-bit.

---

On the off-chance I've misunderstood the question, if you want to set the rightmost (least significant) bit to zero, all you need is:

```
num = num - (num % 2);
```

This simply subtracts one from odd numbers and nothing from even numbers, effectively making the result binary `xxxxxxx0`.

For clearing a *specific* bit where bit 0 is the least significant, use:

```
num = num & ~(1 << bitpos);
```

This sets up a bit mask ike `00001000` and inverts it to `11110111` so that anding it will clear the relevant bit:

```
  xxxxxxxx
& 11110111
  --------
  xxxx0xxx
```

Just make sure you're using unsigned integers, it *may* not behave as you expect for signed values.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this:

```
printf("%d \n", n&(n-1));
```

This actually works. Because:

```
1010 = 10        111 = 7
1001 =  9        110 = 6
----             ---
1000 =  8        110 = 6
```

Hope you understand the idea..

ref: [Turn off the rightmost bit of an integer](http://www.ritambhara.in/turn-off-the-rightmost-bit-of-an-integer/) (read this)

Or you can modify your code like followings:

```
int POS(int n)
{
    int p=0;

    while(!(n&1))
    {
        p++;
        n=n>>1;
    }

    return p;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that the simplest way is to use expression

```
n & n - 1
```

Also you can use the following  straightforward approach

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int reset_bit( int x )
{
    if ( x != 0 )
    {
        unsigned int n = 1;
        while ( !( x & n ) ) n <<= 1;
        x ^= n; 
    }

    return x;
}

int main()
{
    for ( int x = 1; x < 16; ++x )
    {
        std::cout << std::hex << x << '\t' << reset_bit( x ) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
3   2
4   0
5   4
6   4
7   6
8   0
9   8
a   8
b   a
c   8
d   c
e   c
f   e
```