# Turn off the rightmost set bit

Tags: c++, bit

```
int n;
        cin>>n;
        int i=1,m=1;
        while(n&i==0)
        {
            i=i<<1;
            m++;
            
        }
        //now flip mth set bit from right;
        int ans=n^(1<<(m-1));
        cout<<ans<<endl;
```

What is the mistake in the above code for **unsetting the rightmost bit of an integer**?

Comment: to turn off the rightmost set bit of m just use `m & (m - 1)`. [Off rightmost set bit of an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27540201/995714), [Unset the rightmost set bit (duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4703970/995714)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Off rightmost set bit of an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27540201/off-rightmost-set-bit-of-an-integer)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why bitwise operators require parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42815421/why-bitwise-operators-require-parentheses)

Comment: As written, it looks like a homework problem. Normally on Stack Overflow we'd expect you to give an actual example of a bad input, i.e. a value of `n` which should give one outcome but gives another outcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++ `==` operator has higher [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `&` operator, so `n&i==0` won't be what you want.
Use `(n&i)==0` instead of that.